# convert array string to int angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have array like this:

```
vm.array = ['214','2912','82'];
```

I use map convert to int but not work

```
vm.newar = vm.array.map(Number);
```

I render in html but nothing in newar

```
{{vm.newar}}
```

Where my wrong. Pls help me

Here is demo
https://plnkr.co/edit/sgJaW3KgknBlg7egjQ2m?p=preview

Comment: it's correct.I think you have problem in define `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: When i display `{{vm.array}}` it working fine , but new ar is nothing

Comment: please create a demo.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/sgJaW3KgknBlg7egjQ2m?p=preview @HadiJeddizahed here my demo

Comment: please see this https://plnkr.co/edit/IRYdm9mmXTNwvHgPoDg8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your business to get data as this. so you can use `parseInt` function for convert `string` to `integer` .

**changes in** ***services.js***

```
function get(){
    return  $http.get('test.php').then(function(response){
         angular.forEach(response.data,function(d){
              arr.push({masp:d.masp,tensp:d.tensp,gia:d.gia});
               money.push(parseInt(d.gia));
        })
     return response.data; 
    })
}
```

[<kbd>***Demo***</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/IRYdm9mmXTNwvHgPoDg8?p=preview)